# How can I use file.listFiles() to list subdirectories and files also

Tags: java, subdirectory, filelist, filefilter

I'm using `file.listFile()` to list the files and directories in a specified path. The reason I'm using `file.ListFile()` is because I'm using a FileFilter based on if the user only wants directories return or only files. But the result I have is that it only lists the folders and files in the path specified and not subfolders and files. This is what I'm working with right now:

```
file = new File(directory.getText().trim());

// Used this for testing; ListFiles() is a method
File[] test = ListFiles(directory.getName()); //  I made up that will list the subfolders and files.
results.setListData(test); // Also for testing. results is a JList

// This is what i previously had that only lists folders and file in that directory
results.setListData(file.listFiles(new Filter() {
  public boolean accept(File file) {
    if (directories.isSelected()) {
      // Directories checkBox
      if (files.isSelected()) {
        // Files checkBox
        // FILES && DIRECTORIES
        return (file.isDirectory() || file.isFile()) && (StringUtils.contains(file.getName(), userInput.getText().trim()));
      }
      // DIRECTORIES
      return (file.isDirectory()) && (StringUtils.contains(file.getName(), userInput.getText().trim()));
      } else {
        if (files.isSelected()) {
          // FILES
          return (file.isFile()) && (StringUtils.contains(file.getName(), userInput.getText().trim()));
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }));
}
```

I'm just not sure how to go about with the filters involved

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`File#listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles) does not state that it walks all subdirectories. So, you'll need to do that yourself. For each directory that is returned from `listFiles()`, you need to call recursively call `listFiles()` on it.

You could do this in the filter, as long as you're collecting all your files in another structure, since you cannot add more files to the result by using the filter alone. And I wouldn't recommend you do that.

You might be better off forgoing the filter and doing something like this:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

public void getFiles(File file) {
    for (File file : file.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (collectDirectories) {
                files.add(file);
            }
            getFiles(file);
        } else {
            if (collectFiles) {
                files.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be easier to not have the filter inline, make it an outside function and call `listFiles()` with the FileFilter function as a parameter?

Comment: That doesn't help you walk all the subdirectories. See my edit.

Comment: The only problem I have using a list is that when I use `results.setListData()` it requires a `File[]` not a list.

Comment: You can easily convert an array to a list and vice versa: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray

Answer (score 0):

I found all the FileNameFilter stuff with subdirs a bit complex.
I use this now:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
   </dependency>

   File inputDir = new File(inputPath.toString());
   Iterator<File> matchesIterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(
            inputDir, new WildcardFileFilter("somefilenamefilter*.xml"), TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
        while (matchesIterator.hasNext()) {
            File someFile = matchesIterator .next();
             ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use [Files.find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-), it's available since Java 8, there is no need of using third party libraries for such simple things.

Comment: in Java 8 we also have `Files.walk()` and `Files.walkFileTree()`

Comment: @user85421 Yes, these are valid options, `Files.walk()` can be used with `filter()` instead of using a matcher with `Files.find()`. `Files.walkFileTree()`can be used with a `FileVisitor`. I don't know which option is the most efficient.